# What's the shortest way to use CSS multiple combinators?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style all the `input` and `select` from inside a certain `div` in a certain manner. I know I can do (1)

```
#divNew select {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left:1em;
}
#divNew input {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left:1em;
}
```

and I can also do (2)

```
#divNew select,#divNew input {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left:1em;
}
```

and I know I can't do (3)

```
#divNew select,input {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left:1em;
}
```

because (3) applies this style to all `input`, inside and outside `divNew`.

My question is: is this all that is to it? I prefer the shorter option (2), but I feel that the redundant `#divNew` should be eliminated. Can it become even shorter than (2)?

Comment: why 2 is ugly? if you are looking just from the point of readability, why not use css preprocessors?

Comment: Option 2 is more common over option 1, though typically with each element on its own line (i.e. a hard return after each comma - though this is convention rather than a standard). Though if you want to find more elegant and maintainable stylesheets, maybe try looking into [sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax)

Comment: Please share html as well

Comment: @karthick Because it adds a redundant `#divNew`. And I'm not into so big projects as to need another layer of complexity.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks, but I'm not willing to add another layer of complexity, at least not at this point.

Comment: @NagaSaiA That's just a simple question about a trivial css structure (that I couldn't find, though, for the lack of the right keywords). Can't you just abstract the html? Even because the question has already been answered.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've edited the question to eliminate the opinion bias.

Comment: @TylerH I've edited the question to eliminate the opinion bias.

Comment: @Zoe I've edited the question to eliminate the opinion bias.

Answer (score 2):

Your option #2 is the proper way to share declarations amongst a group of selectors. Container nesting like your #3 is not supported, but something similar has been [proposed to the W3C](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2701).

You might find CSS preprocessing tools like sass or less helpful to reduce the boilerplate, at the cost of adding a step to your build pipeline. Though most frontend frameworks nowadays already include a CSS preprocessor like these natively.

Comment: the proposal is accepted and there is already a first draft: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/

Comment: But it's nothing like #3 though. What's closer to #3 is the :is() pseudo. That also appeared in its original form years ago. And it's *still* not available cross-browser yet.

Comment: @BoltClock I forgot about [`:is()`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/is/), which is a great answer and should probably be accepted.